# Returning JSX from a custom hook

Tags: reactjs

Im pretty new to React and i have a problem with JSX in a hook. Im trying to make a custom hook so that it returns JSX. The idea being that a modal with an error will show and be handled in the hook so it doesnt need to be in each component that uses the hook. I have the following:

```
 import {useCallback, useState} from 'react';
 
 const useHttp = (requestObj, setData) => 
 {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [elements, setElements] = useState(null);
    
    const sendRequest = useCallback(() =>
    {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setError(null);
        fetch(requestObj.url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                setData(data);
                let jsx = (<div>Testing conor</div>)
                setElements(jsx);
            })
            .catch(err => 
            {
                setError(err.message);
                setIsLoading(false);
                console.log('There was an error');
            });
    }, []);
 
    return {
        isLoading: isLoading,
        error: error,
        elements: elements,
        sendRequest: sendRequest
    }
} 
 
export default useHttp;
```

When I try to run the project I get in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|                 setIsLoading(false);
|                 setData(data);
>                 let jsx = (<div>Testing conor</div>)
|                 setElements(jsx);
|             })
    at eval (useHttp.js:1)
    at Object../src/hooks/useHttp.js (main.c31b3f1b1129869704a7.bundle.js:2391)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.c31b3f1b1129869704a7.bundle.js:2425)
    at eval (OwnerSearch.tsx:14)
    at Object../src/components/OwnerSearch/OwnerSearch.tsx (main.c31b3f1b1129869704a7.bundle.js:2348)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.c31b3f1b1129869704a7.bundle.js:2425)
    at eval (App.tsx:11)
    at Object../src/App.tsx (main.c31b3f1b1129869704a7.bundle.js:2326)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.c31b3f1b1129869704a7.bundle.js:2425)
    at eval (index.tsx:10)
```

Anyone able to tell me a.) if i can do this at all, b.) if so, then how?

thanks

webpack config

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    target: "web",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ["src", "node_modules"],
        extensions: [
            ".tsx",
            ".ts",
            ".js",
            ".jsx",
            ".svg",
            ".css",
            ".json",
            ".mdx",
            ".png"
        ],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                  // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                  "style-loader",
                  // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                  "css-loader",
                  // Compiles Sass to CSS
                  "sass-loader",
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '/public/icons/[name].[ext]'
                      }
                  },
                ],
              },

        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: "Spectrum App",
            template: __dirname + "/public/index.html",
            inject: "body",
            filename: "index.html",
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].css",
        }),
    ]
};
```

Comment: Sounds like you didn't configure webpack to transpiler JSX syntax in `.js` files. What transpiler are you using, babel? Please show us its config.

Comment: Does JSX syntax work normally in other files?

Comment: I notice the stack trace includes `.tsx` files. If you want this to be a typescript file with jsx, then you must name your file to end with `.tsx` (`.ts` won't work). `.js` *might* work, but as Bergi pointed out this will depend on your transpiler configuration.

Comment: @NicholasTower My file is a .tsx.

Comment: @Bergi sorry, im new so bear with me here. we are doing this as a team, but the webpack config wasnt done by me. I dont know what a transpiler is. Want me to post my webpack config? its pretty short

Comment: @discodowney the error message says it failed on a `.js` file (`../src/hooks/useHttp.js`). Do you maybe have two files with the same name, one `.js` one `.tsx`?

Comment: added the webpack config there now

Comment: @NicholasTower i was working with a js one earlier but changed it to tsx and never tested after cos i thought it was a webpack config issue. I have another issue but thats a separate thing. Thanks for hte help

Comment: @discodowney Then I suggest to ask the person who did the configuration :-) From the file endings in your webpack config, it looks like you are using TypeScript in the project? Anyway, I suggest to rename the *useHttp.js* file to *useHttp.jsx* or *useHttp.tsx*.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is related to the return part, so if you return an array there, it will not cause any problems.

Also I suggest you to review React documentation about custom hooks.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
   const useHttp = (requestObj, setData) => {
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
   const [error, setError] = useState(null)
   const [elements, setElements] = useState(null)

   const sendRequest = useCallback(() => {
      setIsLoading(true)
      setError(null)
      fetch(requestObj.url)
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => {
     setIsLoading(false)
     setData(data)
     let jsx = <div>Testing conor</div>
     setElements(jsx)
    })
      .catch((err) => {
      setError(err.message)
      setIsLoading(false)
      console.log('There was an error')
      })
   }, [])

 return [isLoading, error, elements, sendRequest]
 }
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem.